# react useEffect is not being executed when unit testing with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that uses `useEffect` its making an api call to redux action called   `props.getPostsInit();`

How would i test this, as of now im getting an error, its not calling the getPostsInit prop

```
  ● <Dashboard/> › Should execute getPostsInit

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

**Dashboard**

```
function Dashboard(props: dashboardProps) {
    // const [title, setTitle] = useState<string>("");
    // const [content, setContent] = useState<string>("");
    // const [value, setValue] = useState<number>(0);
    const didMountRef = useRef<Object>();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!didMountRef.current) {
            props.getPostsInit();
            props.initCommentUpdates();
        } else {
            console.log("this is component didupdate");
        }
    }, []); // array prevents an infinite loop
   ......
```

**Dashboard.test**

```
import React from "react";
import { DashboardComponent as Dashboard } from "./dashboard";
import { shallow, mount, render } from "enzyme";
import PostForm from "../../components/forms/createPost/createPost";
describe("<Dashboard/>", () => {
    let wrapper;
    let useEffect;
    const mockUseEffect = () => {
        useEffect.mockImplementationOnce((f) => f());
    };
    const props = {
        getPostsInit: jest.fn(),
        getPopPostsInit: jest.fn(),
        deletePostInit: jest.fn(),
        postCommentInit: jest.fn(),
        titleError: Boolean,
        bodyError: Boolean,
        posts: [],
        error: [],
        title: "Test",
        postContent: "Another test",
        addTitle: jest.fn(),
        addContent: jest.fn(),
        popPosts: [],
        createPostInit: jest.fn(),
        likePost: jest.fn(),
        dislikePost: jest.fn(),
        initCommentUpdates: jest.fn(),
    };
    beforeEach(() => {
        useEffect = jest.spyOn(React, "useEffect");
        mockUseEffect();
        wrapper = shallow(<Dashboard {...props} />);
    });

    it("Should render dashboard component", () => {
        expect(wrapper).toHaveLength(1);
    });

    it("Should execute getPostsInit", () => {
        expect(props.getPostsInit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jest.spyOn(React, "useEffect");` is looking for `React.useEffect` not `useEffect`

I needed to change

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!didMountRef.current) {
        props.getPostsInit();
        props.initCommentUpdates();
        console.log("test");
    } else {
        console.log("this is component didupdate");
    }
}, []); // array prevents an infinite loop
```

to

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!didMountRef.current) {
        props.getPostsInit();
        props.initCommentUpdates();
        console.log("test");
    } else {
        console.log("this is component didupdate");
    }
}, []); // array prevents an infinite loop
```

Now its working fine, im seeing the `console.log("test")` in the test

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to Functional Components, the enzyme shallow rendering API is not robust enough (as of February 2020) to handle various scenarios for functional components.

You might be required to fully render it using [mount()](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/mount.html) instead.

```
wrapper = mount(<Dashboard {...props} />);
```

Comment: @BARNOWL all of them? I was only expecting the second test to fail. As for the first test, there was no wrapper length?